# Desktop Display Locked on VNC Client accessing Centos 7 Compute Engine

Tags: remote-desktop, centos7, vnc, google-compute-engine

I have a centos 7 compute engine. It has `vncserver` installed. I have started `vncserver :1` and can check it is running:

```
$ vncserver -list
TigerVNC server sessions:
X DISPLAY #     PROCESS ID
:1              26094
```

I can check the local host:

```
$ nc localhost 5901
RFB 003.008

$ nc localhost 22
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
```

I am using a Windows7 PC to connect and the TigerVNC client **version 6.0.1 for Windows-64bit**

When I run it, it prompts for a *password*. It *accepts* this and on the log I see:

```
Fri Nov 25 16:29:54 2016  vncext:      VNC extension running!  vncext: Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5901  vncext:  created VNC server for screen 0 xterm: cannot load font '-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso10646-1' gnome-session-is-accelerated: llvmpipe detected.

Fri Nov 25 16:30:27 2016  Connections: accepted: 85.237.223.111::63460 SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.8

Fri Nov 25 16:30:28 2016  SConnection: Client requests security type VncAuth(2)

Fri Nov 25 16:30:44 2016  VNCSConnST:  Server default pixel format depth 24 (32bpp) little-endian rgb888  VNCSConnST:  Client pixel format depth 24 (32bpp) little-endian rgb888
```

On the **client**, I enter & it **accepts the password and connects**, as I have previously set up the *firewall rules for vnc-server*, including a **label on the server**.

However, all it displays is a *coloured screen with a pattern on it of tiles in various shades of green*, and a *digital clock display in the centre showing the 24 hour clock* and the *day and date*, as if the screen is locked and I can't unlock it to get to the desktop.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: I would first look at processes running on the Centos VM to find out if the issue really is that the screen is locked. You can see all running processes on the system with: `ps -fA --forest | less` Then look for a sub-tree of processes that looks like X clients.

Comment: Here's the output from ps -fA :

Comment: /usr/bin/gnome-session --session=gnome-classic  
  \_ /usr/bin/ssh-agent /etc/X11/xinit/Xclients  
  \_ /usr/libexec/gnome-settings-daemon  
  \_ /usr/bin/gnome-shell  
  |   \_ ibus-daemon --xim --panel disable

Comment: There's a full sub-tree but too long to post here.

Comment: Initially you get an "Authentication required" screen, which will not accept passwords. Which password is needed here? If you cancel it you get the blank screen previously mentioned.

Comment: @Alex Information updated with processes and behaviour above this comment.

Comment: You can edit the question to include relevant information.

Comment: Ok first problem here resolved. Updated packages for tigervnc. I was then able to 1) Re-start vncserver 2) Connect with tigervnc client (on windows). I was then presented with the authentication screen asking for a password. When I cancelled this, I got through to the gnome desktop set-up. I was able to complete this Ok so it was working.

Comment: Second problem. The same authentication screen came up when I trued to authenticate an attached disk. Password wasn't accepted (as before). So from a terminal / ssh session I ran 'sudo bash' and then used passwd to re-set the root password, which then worked when authentication requested next. So the main problem was the root password authentication. Problem resolved and thanks @Alex

Comment: @lsrusty I can see from your comments that you have resolved this issue. As such, you can post the solution as an answer for other community members who may be seeing this same issue.

Answer (score 1):

OP has posted a comment saying the issue is resolved, I am posting his comment for other users looking for solution:

> Second problem. The same authentication screen came up when I trued to authenticate an attached disk. Password wasn't accepted (as before). So from a terminal / ssh session I ran 'sudo bash' and then used passwd to re-set the root password, which then worked when authentication requested next. So the main problem was the root password authentication. Problem resolved and thanks

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else having this problem, I found the solution.

The OP said:

> However, all it displays is a coloured screen with a pattern on it of tiles in various shades of green, and a digital clock display in the centre showing the 24 hour clock and the day and date, as if the screen is locked and I can't unlock it to get to the desktop.

The answer is very simple: click the left mouse button at the bottom center of the screen and drag it upward. The desktop will be revealed. Simple, but frustrating when nothing seems to allow you to get past the first screen.